# Apply Bold to Cell Value inside the text string of a HTMLbody

Tags: html, vba, email

I am having trouble with applying Bold on a part of a sentence for an automatically generated email.

In my VBA script:

```
Public strBody     As String
.HtmlBody = strBody
Dim FormulaCell     As Range
Dim FormulaRange    As Range


For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
```

I am able to **Bold** a whole sentence using `"< b >" & "**Text Here**" & "< /b >" &`

But it seems impossible to apply the same logic to a more complex sentence, or a referenced value.

```
strBody = "Hello, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & " with the mention: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "C").Value & " is nearing its Due Date: "
```

What I would like to Bold in the above sentence is the value of the FormulaCells.

```
strBody = "Hello, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Your task : " & **Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value** & " with the mention: " & **Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "C")**.Value & " is nearing its Due Date: "
```

So it would look something like that in my email:

> Hello
>
> Your task : **Eat Potatoes** with the mention: **Potatoes are Delicious** is nearing its Due Date:

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited

```
strBody = "<p>Hello</p>, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "<p>Your task : <b>" & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & _
          "</b> with the mention: <b>" & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "C").Value & _
          "</b> is nearing its Due Date: </p>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! It looks like this should be right, although it still don't appear as bold in my email and somehow, the vbNewLine doesn't work anymore ... Switching the vbNewLine for <br> also doesn't work

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 and Outlook 2010, if this can help.

Comment: Make sure you're setting the mail type to HTML and see my edits about for line breaks

Comment: Somehow works flawlessly now :) Not sure what changed but everything's good. Thanks a whole lot Tim.